# Most Efficient way to compare a value in a table to another set of values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am in the middle of a project where i need to be able to get a value (phone number) from one table then compare it to another set of numbers (phone number rates) that are in another table and i was wondering what the most efficient way to do this would be?

I would be using PHP and then calling SQL from that but which is most efficient way to search a table to compare

for example would it be quicker/slower if my rates table was from smallest to largest or visa versa?

0
00
000

or

000
00
0

And how would i code this to make it as quick as possible as i am comparing around 60k lines per time i run this script

Please see below for example of the two tables:

```
Table 1: Phone Numbers

Date, CLID, DNID, Duration
10/3/14, 01344883333, 01344883321, 60
10/3/14, 01344883333, 07839451009, 60
10/3/14, 01344883333, 07767045933, 60


Table 2: Rates

prefix, description, cost
44, UK - Local, 0.005
07760, UK - Mobile - Vodafone, 0.05
07760,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
07765,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
07766,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
077670,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
077671,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
077672,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
077673,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
077674,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
077675,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
077676,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
077677,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
077678,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
077679,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
07768,UK - Mobile - Vodafone,0.05
```

Comment: Give us a little more detail about what your search process would look like.  For example, what does your key (the thing you are using to look up a rate with) look like?  Is it an area code?

Comment: increased the amount of detail

Comment: So it's just rates by prefix?  Put the rates into an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (prefix -> key, rate -> value), and look them up by key.

Comment: there is 46,000 rates surely thats not the quickest or most memory efficient way?

Comment: If you're looking up a rate by prefix, a map data structure of some sort (using either a hash table or BST) is absolutely the best and fastest way to retrieve the rate.  Or, y'know, just put the rates in a SQL Database table, and index the prefix.

Comment: do you have any examples or info on map's? i am not familiar with them

Comment: http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs210/fall09/Slides/Maps.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get this down from 60K lines per search (I assume that's the number of rows in your Rates table), down to the max length - min length of any prefix by running one query at a time until you got your answer like this:

If the max length of any prefix is 6 characters, and you're searching for the rate for the phone number '07767045933', then search for the rate like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Rates r
WHERE r.prefix = LEFT('07767045933', 6)
```

If no result, then search for:

```
SELECT *
FROM Rates r
WHERE r.prefix = LEFT('07767045933', 5)
```

etc., down to your minimum prefix size.

Equality searches like this can utilize an index. Ensure that there is an index on `Rates(prefix)`.

Or course, you could extract the substring from the phone number in PHP instead of SQL. Using a prepared statement, there would be little overhead in switching out the string until you found the rate.